# Explicit carriage-return character in \write

Tags: write, write-file

Is it possible to `\write` and explicit carriage-return character in LaTeX?

Reason for this question: I have workflow where a latex run generates output for another program, which requires CRLF line endings. I know I can use unix2dos (or similar tools) to convert the file afterwards, (or call them via `\write18`) but it would be more elegant if I could generate files with CRLF line endings on a Linux system without an additional tool.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can add simply the `^^M` character at the end of the `\write` parameter:

```
\newwrite\w
\immediate\openout\w=test.txt

{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
  \gdef\writecrlf#1#2{\immediate\write#1{#2^^M}}%
}

\writecrlf\w{First line}
\writecrlf\w{Second line}

\bye
```

The file `test.txt` has CRLF at the ends of the lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a follow-up question: This solution works with luatex, but not with xetex nor with pdftex. With pdftex and xetex, one ends up with a literal "^^M" in test.txt.

Comment: @sslbrg what you can do with `pdftex`: create a file `crlf.tcx` with only single line where is only single number `13`. Save this file to the `~/texmf/web2c` directory (the `~` means users home directory). Then run `pdftex -translate-file=crlf.tcx test.tex`.

Comment: @sslbrg for  `xetex` you can use `xetex --8bit`.

Answer (score 2):

Using LuaLaTeX you can switch of escaping of `^^` while writing. So, e.g.

```
%!TeX LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
  \gdef\writewithcrlf#1#2{%
    \directlua{texio.setescape(0)}%
    \write#1{#2^^M}%
    \directlua{texio.setescape(1)}%
  }%
\endgroup
\newwrite\txtfile
\begin{document}
Test:
\openout\txtfile{\jobname.txt}
\writewithcrlf\txtfile{This line ends with CRLF.}
\write\txtfile{This line ends with LF only.}
\closeout\txtfile

\end{document}
```

would write a file, where the first line ends with CRLF and the second with LF only. Here is the hexdump of the generated file:

```
00000000  54 68 69 73 20 6c 69 6e  65 20 65 6e 64 73 20 77  |This line ends w|
00000010  69 74 68 20 43 52 4c 46  2e 0d 0a 54 68 69 73 20  |ith CRLF...This |
00000020  6c 69 6e 65 20 65 6e 64  73 20 77 69 74 68 20 4c  |line ends with L|
00000030  46 20 6f 6e 6c 79 2e 0a                           |F only..|
00000038
```